# How is this possible?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

One day, I was going to school. I saw an old man. He said that he will pay me if I answered his question properly.

> If we add 2 into 10 it will be 8, i.e. 10+2=8
>
> If we subtract 2 from 10 it will be 12, i.e. 10-2=12

I forget that the old man was renovating his house.
**How is this possible?**

Comment: Worst possible title !

Comment: Maybe he forgot to add a minus sign (-) before the 10 and the answer?

Comment: This is a task for your maths teacher.  When you get to school, tell him there's a strange man offering money to school children and let him deal with the problem.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan Aside from the horrendous title, this suddenly took a very dark turn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By renovating his house he could be painting ?

> He have a wall to paint.
>   10m<sup>2</sup> are already painted. 
>   By painting 2m<sup>2</sup>of the wall 8m<sup>2</sup> left to paint.
>   10+2 = 8
>   
>   And 
>   
>   By removing 2m<sup>2</sup> of paint it left 12 m<sup>2</sup> to paint. 10 -2 =12

Comment: Isn't that subtraction? 10m² wall - 2m² painted = 8m² yet to paint.

Comment: @Phylyp  you add up 2m to the 10m so it make 12m painted and 8m left to paint so 10m+2m=12m painted and 10m+2m =8m left to paint

Comment: That is a feat of logic that should go down in the annals of history.  What does the first fact:  10 sq/m are already painted have to do with the second fact:  If 2 sq/m are then painted 8 sq/m will be left to be painted?  Are you repainting some of the wall?

Answer (score 13):

I think:

> This can be seen as addition of electrons to a mix of
>  protons/electrons (Net charge $10^+$)
>
>  If we add 2 electrons to this body net charge will become $8^+$
>
>  If we subtract 2 electrons from this body and net charge will become
>  $12^+$

Comment: The old man don't know what are the electrons and protons. He will be confused with this answer

Answer (score 11):

> It can be years **B**efore **C**hrist. 
>  10 BC + 2 = 8 BC 
>  10 BC - 2 = 12 BC

Comment: If you add 10bc+2bc=12bc

Comment: @rudra he is talking about the timeline.

Comment: @prog_sahil read the question again i have given a hint over there.

Comment: @rudra: Arguably, this fits with the tip, since Jesus was a carpenter :)

Comment: @rudra how do you know what he knows? you just met him on the road. Little you know, he can be a MIT scholar.

Answer (score 2):

*renovating his house* could mean that the old man was talking about:

> [Subterranean floors (underground floors)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storey#Subterranean_floors): Floors below the ground level.

So:

> `10 + 2 = 8`     => go up 2 floors from the 10th subterranean floor and you're at the 8th subterranean floor.
>  `10 - 2 = 12`    => go down 2 floors from the 10th subterranean floor and you're at the 12th subterranean floor

Answer (score 2):

Since the tag is mathematics and is a calculation-puzzle, here is a *partial* one

> In logical binary **XOR** operation (which is a **+** inside a circle), the following holds good:
>   2 + 10 = 0010 + 1010 = 1000 (which is 8)

Comment: The old man doesn't know about computer

Comment: @rudra That's [mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra). Heavily used in computers, but mathematics nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

This question has already an accepted answer, but I would add a more generic one:

> Basically anything where the 10 and the 2 have different signs works